# Remove niceScroll to enable default browser scroll

Tags: wordpress, nicescroll

I got Ember Pro theme and it came with built in `niceScroll`. I want to remove it but can't find the way how to do it.

The reason because I want to remove it is that there is an issue: when the mouse cursor is on iframe content, then I can't scroll, I tried the same iframe for my other page, and with that all's good. Here are the links: 
http://exe4um.lv/biletes/ and http://valmierashk.lv/biletes/

The iframe is API from ticket service. So the question is how can I disable nicescroll on `exe4um.lv` page to enable browser's default scrollbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below function in function.php file

```
<?php
function myscript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        /* $('html').getNiceScroll().remove();*/
        $(".page-template-default").getNiceScroll().remove();
    });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myscript' );
?>
```